# Can't install ExpressJS - npm is throwing an error

Tags: node.js, express, npm

When I try to install ExpressJS with the command npm install -g express, I get the following errors:

[image]

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `node -v` gives 0.10.something.
Get rid of it and install a newer version of node from nodejs.org. Also try removing `node_modules` and `npm install` everything again.

Comment: That's not the case. "node -v" returns "v7.1.0".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I fixed the problem by uninstalling the latest version and installing the currently recommended one for most users - version 6.9.1.

The cause of the problem still remains unknown.